# How to count table Horizontal in mysql database?

Tags: php

I have a table with 15 Columns `ID`, `USERNAME`, `PASSWORD`, `EMAIL`, `TELEPHONE`, `FAX`, `ADDRESS`, `COUNTRY`, `CITY`, `NATIONALITY`, `EDUCATION`, etc in mysql database.

There is some required fields and optional fields. Users will fill the required fields and some optional fields. I need to give every user *completeness score* (e.g. `Completeness Score 40%`) to increase there attention to fill all optional fields.

How can I do that in PHP? I've tried to do it by ( SELECT COUNT WHERE ) - but without any result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposed the table is called "users", you do

```
SQL: 'select * from users where id=X'
```

(Without adding any of the optional fields in the WHERE clause!)

Then later in PHP, you do something like this:

```
if (strlen($row['username'])>1)
    $score += 10;
if (is_valid_email($row['email']))
    $score += 10;
```

... et cetera. There might be better ways of doing this. It is just to give you an Idea! This is a very basic question, you might want to learn some more! Cheers.